# Matching no. of records from two tables in Sql?

Tags: sql

Suppose in table A,there are two columns say Agent and policy_number where agent=1101 has 20 policies under it.In table B,that same agent has 21 policies under it.I need a solution where it will check if the agent has the number of policies in Table B.If the records matches it will insert into a new table otherwise the non-matched records will go into an error table.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? Which DBMS did you use?

Comment: 1.I use Sql server

Comment: 2.Table A has two columns: Agent where the values are 1101,1102,1103,1104 and Policy_number 1,2,3,4 respectively,where Table B has two columns: Agent where the values are 1101,1101,1102,1103 and Policy_number 1,2,3,4 respectively.